# Node-red delay 1k+ message

Tags: json, node-red

My problem is the following, I use a watchnode to see for csv files arriving into a ftp server. 
I parse it like so :

```
    payload:{DATE:12344,ID:970005,CONSO:1.344MHw},  
    topic:"INSERT INTO TABLE test VALUES (12344,970005,1.344)",  
    filename:/home/.../test.csv, 
    delay:1500
    parts:{index:0,ch:\n,type,string,id:25401f72.a66b,count:null}  
    _msgid:f3fda651.b7d718
```

So I need to put DATE,ID and CONSO into a flexmodbus server. 
My problem is that whenever a file comes, it represents 1k+ objects.
To allow the server to process 1 object before going to the next one, I need to add some delay. So I add msg.delay.
But I can't manage to make it work with a delay node thus I chose to overwrite the delay argument with msg.delay.
Anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `msg.delay` will not overwrite the value included in the `delay` node config. If you want to specify the delay as part of the message then you need to leave the value blank in the config.

Also the delay is from the time the message arrives at the `delay` node, not between each message. If you want to space the messages out then you need to use the `delay` node in rate limiting mode.

Comment: Yep figured it out and it now works. I just nedded to put my sql querie after the delay otherwise it wouldn't aplly the rate limit since it's based on msg.topic. Thank you :)